# Remove iPad Ribbon/ Zoom Controls Overlay On An Embedded iFrame Google Map?

Tags: ipad, google-maps, iframe

Is there anyway to turn off the iPad ribbon/ zoom controls overlay that shows on a `<iframe>` Google map.

I can't find a screenshot but if you embed a google map using an `<iframe>` the iPad automatically adds an overlay.

Anybody...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using the default embedded map from maps.google.com.

If you want more customization of the appearance of your map, I suggest looking into Google Maps API V3:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

This lets you construct a map, and decide what controls to show.